# Avoid set as const to don't loose information while returning in function in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is this even possible? Let's clarify it a little bit more:

Having a base object with colors:

```js
const DEFAULT_COLORS = { WHITE: '#fff' } as const
```

this won't loose any information. I mean, when I type "DEFAULT_COLORS." Typescript will suggest me all the colors available in the object, and throw errors too if the color doest not exists.

What I want to make now is a function that will extend that object with new colors, but no need to implement "as const" again and with no loose of information, because I am making a component library and I don't want the user to have to do that in every function that will modify the default theme options:

```js
const extendColors = <T extends Record<string, string>>(newColors: T) => ({ ...DEFAULT_COLORS, ...newColors } as const)
```

But this is not working. When I assing it to a variable only the keys are preserved, all the new values are typed with string type.

```js
const colors = extendColors({ RED: '#FF0000' })
```

Is there some way of doing this or am I missleading some concepts about Typescript?

I now if the user type it as const the values are preserved too, but this is the point of the question, I just simply don't want him to implement it like this:

```js
const colors = extendColors({ RED: '#ff0000' } as const)
```

Thank you so much in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

It seems if I add Readonly to T it preserve all the information, however I still want to listen another opinions to learn more about this

My solution

```js
const extendColors = <T extends Record<string, string>>(newColors: Readonly<T>) => ({ ...DEFAULT_COLORS, ...newColors } as const)
```